# Time-step of numerical simulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

I am doing a numerical simulation including a double quantum dot and a periodic probing signal. The simulation works in a very simple way:

1. take the initial state at $t=0$ to be $\psi_0$
2. evaluate the periodic Hamiltonian at $t$ and find the new state as $\psi (t+dt) =e^{- \frac{i}{\hbar} H(t) dt} \psi(t)$
3. increase the time by $t =t+dt$, if this new $t$ is smaller than the integration time go back to step 2

Here, $dt$ is the time-step of the simulation. After working with this method for a few weeks, I realized that some of the quantities that I calculate from $\psi(t)$ strongly depend on $dt$. In some cases this means a significant oscillation as $dt$ changes. My original value for $dt$ was $dt=0.001 \cdot T$, where $T$ is the period of the probing signal. For the time evolution, decreasing the time-step does not change the state vector itself, which makes me think that my original time-step is good.

I think this problem is related to the numerical solution of differential equations in general. I recall from my previous studies that when solving the differential equation of the harmonic oscillator numerically with some naive method (I could not find the name of the method) the energy of the system is not conserved. Realizing this one can somehow force energy conservation with another, more sophisticated method (Runge-Kutta I think) and the energy of the system will be conserved.

I think this is related to my problem as I am trying to calculate the expectation value of the energy of the system based on the numerically estimated density matrix.

Is there a better way to solve the Schrödinger equation numerically?

Comment: For tiniy $dt$, using $e^{- \frac{i}{\hbar} H(t) dt}=1- \frac{i}{\hbar} H(t) dt$ may perhaps prevent some numerical instabilities?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It is not a good idea. the approximation destroys the unitary evolution.

Comment: I think that you should provide some details about the algorithm you use for evolving the state. Do you directly evaluate the action of the time evolution operator or do you use some approximation? It would be also useful to know which quantities you are calculating.

Comment: I am going to edit the question to provide more details.